# Java forEach lambda throws concurrentModificationException

Tags: java, foreach, java-8

What could be the reason that below method throws `ConcurrentModificationException`?

```
static Set<String> setOfAllocAccountsIn(final @NotNull Execution execution) {
        final Set<String> allocAccounts = new HashSet<>();
        execution.legs().forEach(leg -> leg.allocs().forEach(alloc -> {
            if (alloc.account() != null) {
                allocAccounts.add(alloc.account());
            }
        }));
        return allocAccounts;
    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
"java.util.ConcurrentModificationException:
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at com.client.stp.util.DealsBuilderUtil.setOfAllocAccountsIn(DealsBuilderUtil.java:146)
    at com.client.stp.builder.GridDealsObjectBuilder.build(GridDealsObjectBuilder.java:47)
    at com.client.stp.processor.DealToPDXMLTransformer.transform(DealToPDXMLTransformer.java:29)
    at com.client.stp.processor.WorkPartitionerEngine.lambda$onEventSubmit$0(WorkPartitionerEngine.java:40)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

With simple `for-loop` it works fine. The method is called by multiple threads with its own copy of execution object.

Solution which worked with simple for loop:

```
 static Set<String> setOfAllocAccountsIn(final @NotNull Execution execution) {
        final Set<String> allocAccounts = new HashSet<>();
        for (final ExecutionLeg executionLeg : execution.legs()) {
            for (final ExecutionAlloc executionAlloc : executionLeg.allocs()) {
                if (executionAlloc.account() != null) {
                    allocAccounts.add(executionAlloc.account());
                }
            }
        }
        return allocAccounts;
    }
```

I feel that it has something to do with static method and its local variable accessed by multiple threads but per theory that will be thread local variable and are not shared. Give me some time to put down some simple example.

Comment: What does the stacktrace say.

Comment: What is `legs`, `allocs` and so on?

Comment: @Ben...let me update it with simple example.

Comment: how do you create a copy of `Execution` object?

Comment: "With simple for loop it works fine" , then show the simple `for` loop.

Comment: Does the forEach version fail when you run it on just a single thread? If not, I wouldn't be surprised if the simple for loop also fails occasionally when running it on multiple threads.

Comment: @ShashiShankar you've also forgotten to post the stack trace as Kayaman mentioned.

Comment: @Aominè...updated stack trace but let me come up with some simple example to replicate the issue.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Is it possible that one of the methods modifies one of the collections involved (eg maybe `executionAlloc.account()` modifies on of the collections?)

Answer (score 2):

Your logic can be like this :

```
return execution.legs().stream()
            .flatMap(leg -> leg.allocs().stream())
            .map(executionAlloc -> executionAlloc.account())
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

- You are using `forEach` inside `forEach` (Here I replace it with `flatMap`)
- then you check for each element if `alloc.account()` is null or not (I replace it with `filter`)
- then if the condition is correct you add it to the Set (I replace it with a `collect`)

Comment: Yes, this code is cleaner than the OP's code, but how would making this change solve the `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: @Eran honestly I don't see where the OP can get `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: Since the result of `leg.allocs()` has a `forEach` method, it is not an array but likely a collection, so it should be `leg.allocs().stream()` instead of `Stream.of(leg.allocs())`. Further, you gain a lot, if you do `.map(executionAlloc -> executionAlloc.account())` before the `filter`, as then, the predicate becomes a simple `null`-check (`filter(Objects::nonNull)`) instead of needing to repeat the `account()` call.

Comment: this is correct @Holger thank you for the details, I edit my answer